# Information about dtype of array

Tags: python, types, numpy

I know numpy has methods `numpy.finfo()` for information about a float-based dtype and `numpy.iinfo()` for its integer counterpart. Is there a method that accepts any dtype? Currently I am forced to pick the right one myself:

```
try:
    maxv = numpy.finfo(data.dtype).max
except:
    maxv = numpy.iinfo(data.dtype).max
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think NumPy provides such a function. Just define the function yourself, put it in a module, and import it as necessary. Note that in general using bare `except` is a bad practice. Using except `ValueError` here would be better.

Answer (score 0):

For "any" type I'm pretty sure there's no such method, as that's not a general information.

```
In [7]: np.array([], dtype=object).dtype.itemsize
Out[7]: 8
```

That's an object, generally. Each cell of such an array requires a storage size that can store a memory address. It might reference a Python long, for example, but probably that's not the kind of task you'd use NumPy for.

*Be careful*: Python long casts to int64 unless it's big enough to need more than 64 bits!

```
In [11]: np.array([long(123)]).dtype
Out[11]: dtype('int64')

In [12]: np.array([123456789 ** 1234]).dtype
Out[12]: dtype('object')
```

You can get the information if it's a "float" or "integer" from the `kind` attribute

```
In [14]: np.array([123456789 ** 1234]).dtype.kind
Out[14]: 'O'

In [15]: np.array([long(123)]).dtype.kind
Out[15]: 'i'

In [16]: np.array([2.3, 4.3]).dtype.kind
Out[16]: 'f'
```

You can get it from NumPy by name:

```
{"i": np.iinfo, "f": np.finfo}[data.dtype.kind](data.dtype).max
```